# Array, class and function

Tags: c++11

I don't know what to do with this program.
I have a class like this:

```
const class infoCity{
public:
   queue <int> nei;
   int customUni;
}
```

and in main I have an array of cities like this:

```
int number;
cin>>number;
InfoCity cities[number];
```

after that I need to create a function which will tell me closest way from one point to another so I started write and the problem show up because I don't know how to get cities[number].

```
const int searchWay(int start, int finish){
??--- how do i get information from main cities[number] ?? }
```

Comment: Why don't you start reading some tutorials?

Comment: Well I'm reading one but i also write different program for school. And i don't know what to do with this or under which words to find this problem :{

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand your only issue is that you don't know how to get the field from the array. I'm not sure if you are filling the array correctly or if you have access to the array from the function you are creating, but to get the information you just append a period with the field name afterwards:

```
cities[number].customUni
```

Here is a link on how to use arrays:
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. I have function not inside the main and I want to get information from it. I think it will need some pointer.

Comment: Have the function take the array as a parameter, along with the size of the array if it's a C-Style array. If you know the size of the array at runtime you could look at using [std::array](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) or [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), which would save you passing around an additional size parameter.